# I want to POST the content of a uib-timepicker angular-ui bootstrap tag

Tags: angular-ui-bootstrap

I would like to let the user pick a time using a uib-timepicker tag and POST the result to my server (with a submit button for example).

```
<form class="simple_form vertical_form"
      data-type="json" id="my_form"
      action="url_to_post"
      accept-charset="utf8"
      data-remote="true"
      method="post">
  <div class="field">
    <uib-timepicker
      name="my_time"
      ng-model="event.my_model"
      hour-step="1"
      minute-step="15"
      show-meridian="true">
    </uib-timepicker>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="submit" value="Validate" class="btn btn-success">
  </div>
</form>
```

But when I check to content of the POST method it is empty (I don't get the "my_time" key as I would expect. I guess it is because a "uib-timepicker" does not exactly work as an input field. But I feel like there must be a way to POST the content of that tag.

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by adding hidden input elements with binding to the time picker:

```
<uib-timepicker ng-model="ServiceRestoredTime" name="ServiceRestoredTime" ng-change="changed()" hour-step="hstep" minute-step="mstep" show-meridian="false" show-spinners="false"></uib-timepicker>
<input type="hidden" name="ServiceRestoredTimeParam" value="{{ServiceRestoredTime | date:'HH:mm' }}">
```